# Unable to grab some fields from a webpage having unconventional content

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

When I try to scrape some fields from a webpage using requests, I come across foreign content like the following which I don't find any idea to grab data from. Here goes a tiny portion of that response I'm getting:

```
    I: Qc[
    j~O~_
]S6gMWNougj~Ougp_{
    hr[
        ogL>i
    ]OqNotnYr=nQHOGirKugLKngL[
        Kh
    ][
        uiMpnTnNpSYR: QIZSXNxNpOq_MRnTnN5Nn|nV[
            _SNotnOIh~Rn|9 RIFnQHOuh6Smg\[
                S^\qxf\: sY8OKjL[
                    yhMVnTnO__
                ]RnQHOYhZ_5NotnRn|
            }TYFnQHOIf
        ]W: NotnVZSZY59nQHOuh5
    }uh8Wq_J_{
        hqSmgLZnTnOTg~NxNpOmiLmNotnRnNxNp>8 gr[
            ~NotnW5>
        ]XZ: MQJ6OV5mGWZ|lXnNxNrqz[
            LK9WL[
                xf\:
            }i\[
```

I wish to know if there is any way I can convert the content to regular html or json.

This is some of the addresses supposed to be within those elements:

```
Franklin St
Great Rd
Nonset Path
```

Comment: The site probably has some client-side Javascript to decode that to what you see. You'd have to reverse engineer that (or in general what happens on the site in your browser).

Comment: you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript and convert it to correct text on page - and you will get this text

Comment: What level of account do you have on [propertyradar](https://www.propertyradar.com/pricing)?

Answer (score 6):

The data appears to follow some form of encoding.  Evidence of this, based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555653/3196753).

- Certain text, such as `>QMxnf\:Lg8Oq^7}{h8[~_XN;Np:{Nn|nV]_mf\}m^r}` appears 32 times
- The data is (mostly) limited to ASCII characters suggesting it uses a form of encoding inflation such as Base64, Base85, etc.
- Running the data through popular decoders fails, suggesting it may be ciphered, however [automatic cypher detection](https://www.dcode.fr/cipher-identifier) was inconclusive.
- If the data is both cyphered and encoded, trial and error (with ability to spot common recognizable encoding patterns) is needed
- The data may be encrypted
- The data may use a proprietary obfuscation

Looking into PropertyRadar, it appears [they use an integration service by "Zapier"](https://www.propertyradar.com/integrations), however public information about data format/exchange wasn't readily available.

Last, looking at their [products page](https://www.propertyradar.com/pricing), I can see that some tiers of information are only accessible with a higher monthly subscription plan.  If this is the case, the data you've posted may be deliberately obfuscated to prevent the exact thing you're trying to do from happening.

Regardless, the best way to parse this data is to first reach out to the website's tech support and ask them how.  If they aren't helpful, obtaining (and sharing) some technical documentation about their `v1` API would be a good start, however do so (sharing) with caution as that may come with restrictions that prohibit it from being posted publicly.   If this data is accessible with a higher tier, you may already be in violation of your agreement with them by attempting to reverse-engineer their services.

Answer (score 0):

As this API requires an account, I cannot get the *actual information* (I tried to make an account, but it wouldn't take my phone number). But I can suggest the following:

```py
import requests

url = "" # Enter your url here
data = requests.get(url=url).json()

print(data)
```

If you make `url` [your suggested url](https://national.propertyradar.com/api/v1/lists/556822/items?&Fields=PType,Address,City,SqFt,Beds,Baths,AVM,AvailableEquity,Owner,isSameMailingOrExempt,isListedForSale,inForeclosure,inTaxDelinquency,RadarID&ClientID=H-20220208&SessionID=7c524e5ba8def8e48757098984ebd67202a9ab76&Start=100&Limit=100), it will return the decoded error message, and `data` will be a dictionary of that json response

---

Edit:

Maybe give this a try?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL = "https://national.propertyradar.com/api/v1/lists/556822/items?&Fields=PType,Address,City,SqFt,Beds,Baths,AVM,AvailableEquity,Owner,isSameMailingOrExempt,isListedForSale,inForeclosure,inTaxDelinquency,RadarID&ClientID=H-20220208&SessionID=7c524e5ba8def8e48757098984ebd67202a9ab76&Start=100&Limit=100"

# Must have chromedriver installed, or use driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url=URL)
elem = driver.find_element("Franklin St")
driver.close()
```

Comment: When session expires, the error message shows up in json. However, this is how the [response](https://filebin.net/5kdox6ozzhtyuhq5) looks like.

Comment: Could you try new example please?

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by others, you'll need to figure out which javascript library is parsing this and reverse engineer same.

Its likely that the author has performed a custom obfuscation precisely to avoid the crawling exercise that you seem to have taken up!

Answer (score 0):

```
var chunks = (ResposeString.substr(5) + '').split('');
            var decodedChunks = [];
            for (var i = chunks .length - 1; i >= 0; b--) {
                decodedChunks[i] = String.fromCharCode(chunks[i].charCodeAt(0) - 5)
            }
            var base64text = decodedChunks.join('');
            var FinalResult = window.FR.util.Utils.fix_utf8(FR.util.Utils.base64_decode(base64text));
```

evaluate it inside puppeteer or playwright or selenium